# Calling super with different parameters for derived class than base class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, super

Is it possible to have a derived class which takes different parameters to its constructor than its base class? I'm getting errors when trying to call `super`:

```
class Base {
  constructor (private _myService) {}
}

class Derived extends Base {
  constructor (private _myService, private _myOtherService) {
    super(_myService);
  }
}
```

**Class 'Derived' incorrectly extends base class 'Base'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property '_myService'.**

```
class Derived extends Base {
  constructor (_myService, private _myOtherService) {
    super(_myService);
  }
}
```

**ERRORTS2341: Property '_myService' is private and only accessible within class 'BaseClass'.**

```
class Derived extends Base {
  constructor (private _myOtherService) {
    super();
  }
}
```

**error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.**

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Your `Derived` examples don't extend `Base`...

Comment: Good catch! They were in the examples I was using, but I forgot to type them here.

Comment: Your example 2, after extending `Base`, seems fine: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor%20(private%20_myService)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor%20(_myService%2C%20private%20_myOtherService)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(_myService)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 1):

> What's the correct way to do it?

Don't duplicate `private` in the derived class. Fixed example:

```
export class Base {
  constructor(private _myService: any) {
    console.log(this._myService);
  }
}

export class Derived extends Base {
  constructor(_myService: any, private _myOtherService: any) {
    super(_myService);
    console.log(this._myOtherService)
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what I did in example 2?

Comment: Add annotation : `any`

Comment: Or something else that is closer to truth. I just filled a gap